# I need analog of Application.Evaluate method in MS Word

Tags: vba, ms-word

I've an mathematical expression calculator. For instance: (2+3)*5. The cod works correctly in excel. But in MS Word it doesn't work, becouse there are no Application.Evaluate method in MS Word

I need help with finding an analog of this method in MS Word..

```
Private Sub TextBox1_Change()

    Dim strExpr As String, p As Long, ss As String, qwer As String, i As Integer, a
    On Error Resume Next
    strExpr = TextBox1.Value
    Do
        p = InStr(strExpr, ",")
        If p = 0 Then Exit Do Else strExpr = Left(strExpr, p - 1) & "." & Mid(strExpr, p + 1)
    Loop
    If strExpr = Empty Then
        Label3.Caption = "": Label1.Caption = ""
    Else
        Label3.Caption = Application.Evaluate(strExpr)
        a = Split(Label3.Caption, ",")
        qwer = StrReverse(a(0))
        For i = 1 To Len(qwer)
            If i Mod 3 = 0 Then ss = ss & Mid(qwer, i, 1) & " " _
                Else ss = ss & Mid(qwer, i, 1)
        Next
        Label1.Caption = StrReverse(ss): ss = ""
        If UBound(a) > 0 Then Label1.Caption = Label1.Caption & "," & a(1)
    End If

End Sub
```

But this line of cod doesn't work:

```
Label3.Caption = Application.Evaluate(strExpr)
```

I've changed this line of cod:

```
Label3.Caption = Application.Evaluate(strExpr)
```

to this line:

```
Selection=strExpr
Label3.Caption = Selection.Calculate(strExpr)
```

but, at the same time, the mathematical expression written inside TextBox1 is written / copied into an MS Word document ...

and it returns value with type single...

Comment: You don't provide any examples of what you are trying to evaluate.  You could try adding  a reference to Excel then use Excel.Application.Evaluate.

Comment: Word has no equivalent.

Comment: I'm trying evaluate mathematical expressions such: (2+2)*5

Comment: Pls culd you kindly help me with this: (You could try adding a reference to Excel then use Excel.Application.Evaluate.)...